# Is it allowed to look up tables of another contract?

Tags: smart-contract, table

Imagine if I have an account with contract. Is it allowed for me to look up tables of some another contract from my contract action?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Include the definition of multi_index of the other contract in your source code, and instantiate multi_index with `(code, scope)`. `code` is the account name of the other contract you want to read. (You may pass `_self` usually, because you read and write the multi-index table of your contract.)

The multi-index table of other contracts is read-only. You cannot change its value from your contract.

Comment: can it be private for customers? I mean if I do it, will this table be in traces or raw transaction result?

Comment: @ВладимирГоворухин No, all data recorded in blockchain are public. (Setting table visibility in C++ contract doesn't hide it) Tables are not in trace or receipt, but in state db which is constructed by accumulating transaction execution results.